# JMX connection to tomcat on VirtualBox

Tags: spring, tomcat, vagrant, virtualbox, jmx

I have enabled JMX on my tomcat server with

`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost` and I have a spring app that exposes JMX beans with a `JmxRemoteLifecycleListener` bean:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener" rmiRegistryPortPlatform="10000" rmiServerPortPlatform="10001" />
```

When I run this tomcat instance on virtualbox (using vagrant) I forward ports 10000 and 10001, but when I try to connect to the JMX service (tried with VisualVM and JRockit Mission Control), I am unable to connect. Is there special configuration that needs to be done to connect since it is running on VirtualBox?

Comment: You need to do the `Port forwarding with IPTABLES`

Comment: I have port forwarding setup...

Comment: Are you running VisualVM in same instance or in remote? If remote then just check whether telent is working fine for mentioned port or not.

Comment: Hmm..doesn't seem to be. Works for some of the other forwarded ports. I'll see if that has anything to do with it. Thanks.

Comment: The IPTABLES was the issue. I had a rule that was rejecting all. Thanks. If you post as an answer, I can accept.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff I did that ,  but main thing is that I am happy as your problem is resolved.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help and time in solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the Port forwarding with IPTABLES. Just check whether port is enabled in Iptables.