# Unable to connect profiler (JMC) on VirtualBox VM

Tags: java, networking, virtualbox, jmc

I'm running an application on Weblogic server hosted inside a VirtualBox VM (Windows 2008 Server). To connect JRockit Mission Control Profiler my server aruguments is as below :

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n
```

When I start my server, in ProcessExplorer I can see the **application listening to port 4000**.

But in Mission Control UI, **I'm neither able to see this application in default local connection nor connect as new using manual port configurations**. I'm able to see connections for other Java applications in the same VM.

[image]

My configurations are like this:

- **Guest (VM) OS :** Windows 2008 Server
- **Host OS : Windows 7 VM Network :** Bridged Adapter (Promiscuous : Deny)
- **Server :** Weblogic 12c
- **Java :** 1.6
- **JVM :** Oracle JRockit(R) (build
  R28.2.5-20-152429-1.6.0_37-20120927-1915-windows-x86_64, compiled
  mode)
- **VM :** VirtualBox 4.2.4

The closest answer I could find which seeems to have worked for Linux VM is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168142/jmx-connection-to-tomcat-on-virtualbox).

I tried below :

- Windows Firewall with Advanced Securtiy -> Inbound rules -> Added
  port 4000 with full access
- Windows Firewall with Advanced Securtiy ->
  Outbound rules -> Added port 4000 with full access
- Changed VM Network
  -> Bridged Adapter -> Promiscuous : Allow All
- Changed VM Network -> NAT

But no luck yet. Anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM flags above is for JDWP style debugging and not connecting remotely using JMXRMI which is what JRockit Mission Control is using.

You should run with the -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote properties,
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html

or for JRockit you can also use the shorthand flag -Xmanagement

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionx.htm#BABJDIGF

I would suggest
-Xmanagement:port=4000,ssl=false,authenticate=false

Then you should be able to create a custom jmc connection to server os hostname/ip and port 4000.

If you are running both WLS and JRMC on the same host, you should be able to see the running WLS in the JVM Browser though. If you don't, you can still use the same flags as above.

Comment: You are so right, I had added the parameter for remote debugging and carelessly over sighted for JMC argument. Thanks for spotting. Gosh I need some sleep!